# Read MVS DataSet from java program

Tags: db2, zos, ibm-jvm

I'm trying to access to a DataSet called X.Y.Z;
my code is:

```
ZFile zFile = new ZFile("//X.Y.Z","r");
    try {
        String enc = ZUtil.getDefaultPlatformEncoding();
        InputStream is = zFile.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, enc));
        String line;
        while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        };
    }finally {
        zFile.close();
    }
```

I get this exception:

```
com.ibm.jzos.ZFileException: X.Y.Z: Filename is not a valid MVS dataset or DD name; errno=99 errno2=0x0 last_op=0 errorCode=0x0
    at com.ibm.jzos.ZFile.checkSecurityManager(ZFile.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.jzos.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:475)
    at it.Main.test(MainApp.java:20)
com.ibm.jzos.ZFileException: //'X.Y.Z': fopen() failed; EDC5049I The specified file name could not be located.; errno=49 errno2=0xc00b0641 last_op=50 errorCode=0x21708
    at com.ibm.jzos.ZFile.fopen(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.jzos.ZFile.doZFileOpen(ZFile.java:613)
    at com.ibm.jzos.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:476)
    at it.Main.test(MainApp.java:22)
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Why not define the DD via JCL, and in your code specify the DD?  Why did you tag `db2` for this question?

Comment: I can't use the DD because I don't call this program whit the JCL; I have install this jar inside the db2 as an external stored procedure.

Comment: The exception seems clear, `'TSTCWLMY.L065291.SUN.JAVALOG'` is not found...  (you cannot use read mode for a dataset that does not exist).

Comment: The problem is that the file exist and the name is correct; could it be a problem of permission?

Comment: How do you check the file exists (and with which authid?). When the external sproc runs, a different authid may be involved so your assumptions might not be true.

Comment: I have add a check for the file presence: ZFile.exists("//X.Y.Z") and the program return false ( the file doesn't exist for the program ) but again, the file is present.

Comment: if `X` is the high level qualifier try using `"//'X.Y.Z'"`.

Comment: @meat That's correct; thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the double slash notation is used to refer to a data set on z/OS, it assumes the data set's high level qualifier (HLQ) is the user id of the current user. For example, `//X.Y.Z` would resolve to `MEAT.X.Y.Z` assuming my username was my user id on z/OS. Quotes should be added if the data set specified is the fully-qualified data set name. In your case, `//'X.Y.Z'` would resolve to `X.Y.Z`.